# Kubernetes: traffic forwarding from local ports (UDP, TCP) to specific services

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have a EC2 instance (linux, kubernetes) with public IP address. I want forward data traffic to my services.

Let's assume my public IP address is: **4.32.312.21**  I haven't external dns or sth else and I want redirect traffic like below:

```
 - 4.32.312.21:6600 -> to service-a     //TCP traffic
 - 4.32.312.21:6500 -> to service-b     //UDP traffic
```

My configuration:

```
NAME         TYPE         CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)
service-a    ClusterIP    10.109.38.119    <none>        6600/TCP
service-b    ClusterIP    10.107.10.227    <none>        6500/UDP
```

I try using Node Port-s but the ports have high range (from 30000), and this is not solution.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use NodePort. Why do you say such port range is not a solution?

if you want to stick to those ports for whatever reason you might have, then, assuming you don't want to add more elements like a load balancer, you will need to set iptables rules to forward your 6500/6600 traffic to 30000/30001 for example.

Comment: Thank your for answer! I can add more elements (eg. load balancer) - this is not a problem. Could you describe more your solution with use load balancer.

Comment: @Mateusz if you can use a load balancer, just add your ports as listeners on the load balancer, and the services in Kubernetes exposed with NodePort. In other words, listener 6500 on LB forward to 30000 on EC2, and 6600 to 31000.

Comment: Thank you, but I have one more question - what do you think about using kubernetes ingress? This is not a solution to redirect traffic?

Comment: @Mateusz Ingress works by path, like an Application Load Balancer in AWS. In your case, you're saying you want to have your services exposed on specific ports, 6500 and 6600, so there is no use of Ingress there. Another thing would be if you just wanted to expose a port, let's say 443, and then depending on the path forward to the specific service.